# Having problems with .fadeOut() and .fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

My page makes an AJAX request and fetches an array of image links from the server.

Now, I try to change with images which are there on the page with the ones retrieved from the database like this:

```
function fillContent(phparray, i ){
    if(i == 20){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        return; 
    }

    var img = phparray[i].filepath;
    $(image).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).attr('src', img).fadeIn("fast")
    })
    var timer = window.setTimeout(function(){ fillContent(phparray, ++i)},400);
}
```

Now, what happens is the image fade outs and fadein and most of the images again fade out and fade in then. It's almost like a blink. I tried using, `.hide()` but even that gives me the same problem.

Comment: Posting an example fiddle would help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(image).hide("slow", function(){ $(this).attr('src', img).show("slow");
```

or

```
$(image).fadeOut(SPECIFY_MILLISECONDS_HERE, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', img).fadeIn(SPECIFY_MILLISECONDS_HERE)
    })
```